# Stream Trace to Select Attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, geometric-network, trace

I'm trying to work on a school project, but I only need streams up stream from a certain point. As you can see in the picture, I've run the stream trace tool upstream from a point i've created.

I'm trying to find the total length of the red streams. However, you cannot select attributes from a stream trace. How can I accomplish this task?

[image: Upstream trace results]

Answer (score 4):

From the look of your screen shot it looks like you have used the utility network analyst toolbar and the Trace Upstream option? So... not ArcHydro?

If this is correct then click on the down arrow next to the word Analysis and select options. Under the results tab set results format to *selection*. This will select the polylines and you can compute the total length.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have been more clear, as that was through UNA, but had run through many ArcHydro processes. I completely missed that.